# How to install mysqlclient v2.0.1 in anaconda/conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I try to install mysqlclient v2.0.1 in anaconda/conda

`conda install -n py37 mysqlclient=2.0.1` 
or
`conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" -n py37 mysqlclient=2.0.1`

But I get such error message:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.  

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mysqlclient=2.0.1

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page
```

Where am i wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda Forge has never built `mysqlclient` for **win-64** platform, and Anaconda seems to have given up on the Windows builds after 1.3.14 (~3 years ago). Thus, one cannot install v2.0.1 as a Conda package.

Perhaps consider using the MySQL Connector/Python package instead, which goes by `mysql-connector-python` and is building for all platforms on both the `defaults` and `conda-forge` channels:

```
conda install mysql-connector-python
```

Otherwise, if insisting on `mysqlclient=2.0.1`, one could install it with `pip install` with the environment active.